# How to Create Instance of Modified Object with Added Methods?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to dynamically add methods to a single instance of a class, and then be able to instantiate new objects of that modified class.

Below is a sketch of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
class A
  def add_new_method
     define_singleton_method(:new_method) { puts("hi") }
  end
end

a = A.new
a.add_new_method
B = a.singleton_class
b = B.new
```

Obviously, the above is reasonably impossible with those methods since you clearly shouldn't be able to create a new instance of a singleton. What is the right way to accomplish the same?

Comment: See [this article](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/demystifying-singleton-classes-in-ruby-caf3fa4c9d91). Search "instantiated".

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate singleton classes in Ruby but you can write some code to get the feeling you are doing it.

I would use a class method as the following example

```rb
class A
  def add_new_method
     define_singleton_method(:new_method) { puts("hi") }
     self
  end

  def self.Enhanced
    new.add_new_method
  end
end

b = A.Enhanced
b.new_method
# hi
```